# Using .htaccess to hide .php extension changes visitor IP to the server IP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've noticed that when using Apache(htaccess) to hide .php extension is actually changing the return of the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; from returning the visitors IP to returning the Domain or the server IP.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

that's what I'm using for my htaccess file
and nothing that

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
```

in my php file
is there anyway that could fix the return of  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to be a visitor ip?

Comment: That's... weird. Is this literally all there is? No other rewrite rules? Is the client really a physically different machine from the server?

Comment: nothing else is being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly to echo deceze's comment - this is weird, and I don't think caused by the Apache / htaccess rules here. Is there more going on?

Try using:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARTDED_FOR'] != '') {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

echo $ip_address;
```

Does that give a more accurate IP at least?

Comment: http://wetube.org/php this one is wrong
http://wetube.org/php.php this one is okay

Comment: it's the same php file. the only difference is that i'm including .php with it.

Comment: Very very strange - just created the same htaccess on my local server here and the REMOTE_ADDR was correct in both instances (with and without .php) which is the expected behaviour.

Did you try with the suggested code above to see if you get a different output?

Comment: yes, I've already tried it before and I tried it again after you posted it. it doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

so after almost 4 hours of investigations and hard work. I figured out that the REMOTE_ADDR
is actually cannot be trusted all the time. however i tried something else instead but it didn't work. at the end I knew that $_SERVER has an array. so really that's what I did

```
foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value){
echo $key.'_____'.$value."<br/>";
}
```

and I found this $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
it works just fine. I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This just means your webserver is configured in some very special way. This is *not* a generally applicable problem or solution.

Comment: I know, but please i'm really good with apache
please see the difference between this http://wetube.org/php
and this http://wetube.org/php.php

Comment: i'm sorry, i was doing something with it. try it now. sorry

Comment: Yup, it's weird. ;) I guess one would need to be able to see the entire rest of the Apache configuration to spot the problem. Looks like mod_rewrite is working in reverse proxy mode instead of internal rewrite mode, but I don't know what would cause that without explicit configuration. Maybe ramp up the rewrite log level and study the rewrite log?

Comment: Glad you got sorted - worth noting that the HTTP_X_REAL_IP variable is also potentially untrustworthy - all $_SERVER variables are really.

For future ref / quick access you can see all the $_SERVER vars and more besides by calling:

phpinfo(); 

in any php script.